# WinRT scale and ellipse but keep it centred

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

```
   <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="238" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.3" CenterX="0.5" />

            </TransformGroup>

        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
```

I'm trying to get an Ellipse to Stretch in the center of the screen, however it always stetches to the right - I've been playing around with CenterX thinking that this is setting the Center point?  But it's not having any effect.

Can anyone assist please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [RenderTransformOrigin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.rendertransformorigin.aspx) on the Ellipse to `0.5,0.5` in order to keep it centered:

```
<Ellipse RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
     HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="238" Stroke="Black" 
     StrokeThickness="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1.3" CenterX="0.5" />
        </TransformGroup>
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
</Ellipse>
```